# TYPO3 limit to language binds content

Tags: localization, typo3

I'm using TYPO3 for a multi language web site and I want the localization mode of the frontend to be not binding. Meaning a user limited to the portuguese language should be able to create new elements in portuguese only. If it was binding he couldn't create but only translate the original ([official explanation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_l10nguide/1.1.0/view/1/3/#id1020483))
The issue is I'm limiting the user to portuguese only and when logging with that user he's not able to create any content element be it in default or portuguese only.

And if I give the user default content permissions he's able to delete and create default content which I don't want.

Am I missing somehting? Shouldn't the default behavior be not binding?

Comment: The dafulat behavior really *should be* as you described it and *it is* the behaviour on my installations of TYPO3 (4.5.x).

Comment: I'm using 4.7.2...do you think it might be due to that?

Comment: I don't have a working installation of TYPO3 4.7.x so I cannot test it. Obviously there could have been some change or there could be an unresolved bug that breaks the functionality from previous versions.

Comment: I tried changing every settings I remembered and I don't seem to be able to make it work...an user can't add content if it doesn't have access to default language...do you have any idea where this might be set...only allowing to create content elements with default language permissions? because the user is even able to add a new element but then change from default to the supposed country language.

Comment: What permissions (Limit to languages) do you have set for the group that the user is member of? How are you actually trying to create the content when logged in as that user (Page module, List module)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. On the group the limit to language is unchecked (all of the options). I set the limit to language by user so it's easier. On the Page module I'm not able to create new content elements when the user doesn't have access to default language (limit to language default is checked), but on the List view I can create content selecting the + on the top, but I can't use it on the page because it's a non-used element and I can't place it on the page. The only icons I have on the Page module is copy and create reference and even after I can't paste or add reference.

Comment: Right, so the problem is actually limited to the Page module (I haven't checked that one before) and it all works in the List module. Let me see if I can reproduce it on my installation.

Comment: When you are in the Page module, are you using the Columns mode or the Quick edit? Can you provide a screenshot of what you see in the page module when the user cannot edit anything?

Comment: thanks for the help. You can see what is displayed using the Web->Page module and selecting a page here: http://i49.tinypic.com/2n8r0o4.png

Comment: Oh, you are using TemplaVoila. You should then focus on the possible issues concerning its usage as IMHO the classic Page module doesn't have any issues with the language access settings. I'm sorry I can't help you anymore as I don't use TV.

Answer (score 0):

You can set User rights based on language in Backend User Admin in the user group settings.

1) select your user

- remove everything in the Access Rights tab -> all settings here need to be done now in user group settings.
- tab "General" -> Group -> define new groups with the plus icon

2) User group: default language read-only

- Tab Access Lists -> check "show secondary tabs" and "Include Access lists"
- Tables(listing): Page, Page Content
- Tables (modify): nothing
- limit to languages: Default
- Set additional fields as you need them

3) User group: portugese read/write

- Tab Access Lists -> check "show secondary tabs" and "Include Access lists"
- Tables(listing): Page, Page Content
- Tables (modify): Page Content
- limit to languages: Portugese
- Set additional fields as you need them

About Binding: 
Binding is something that is based on records - and is not about user rights. It means: Record Nr. 123 in language english corresponds to record nr. 334 in language danish. Usually this is created with the duplicate content button. This is quite usefull, if you want to translate text with image - you don't have to upload the image again if you duplicate your content in another language.

If you need more Rights on subparts of the Tree, check you Access module, and if this is not sufficient, use be_acl Extension.

Comment: First, from the approach you are referring I would need to create a different group for each user which makes no seance. And second it doesn't work...I can't create any content if the user belongs to the group and Default isn't part of the allowed languages. What you are saying is obviously what I did initially but by doing that I can't create new content elements.

Comment: @Andrea: Can you explain why (according to you) the settings need to be done on the group record? The limit to a language can be done on the user record.

Comment: And even if I do it on the user record I need to set the Default language otherwise it's not possible to create content

Comment: This is correct, because you can not create a translation without a source and thus you must have the right to create source entries before the translation.