# TYPO3 disable icons for user group

Tags: css, permissions, typo3

My question is quite simple...I'd like to hide some typo3 backend icons when a user is part of a group. More precisely I want to hide the edit pencil for the content elements. How can I do that? Somehting like option.disableDelete.[table] but for edit

If there isn't any typoscript configuration, is there a easy way to inject css to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

You should not hide things via CSS. Just do not give them the rights to edit content elements. Afair the [getting started](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_quickstart/1.0.0/view/1/9/) manual has some infos about user rights. It is [translated in many languages](https://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already tried that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035914/typo3-limit-to-language-binds-content#comment17877462_13035914

Answer (score 0):

`TYPO3 CMS 6.0` will hide the edit icons in the `page module` if the user can not edit the element.
http://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Core.git?a=commitdiff;h=f239ca8530cef1746f14ec24e2e8c136d2371923

Answer (score 0):

Using this extension you will not be able to disable editing from a security point of view but you can hide the edit pencil in the list interface: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_modlist_actions